# Local Jenkins server does not have slave.jar or slave-agent.jnlp - Impossible to create slave/build node

Tags: jenkins, slave

I have a local Jenkins server that I've set up and created jobs for. I am trying to register new slave/build machines, but Jenkins refuses to offer a slave.jar or slave-agent.jnlp

These files simply don't exist. Permissions are currently set to be granted in full to every user. When visiting the the agent node in Jenkins from the new slave machine, I simply see the blue "Launch Agent" button and not the orange "Launch" option that downloads and runs the slave.jar file.

I've looked through many tutorials and all act as if this process is automatic, and they all show an orange "Launch" button that will download the slave.jar. No one seems to have had this problem yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: No options to download]

[image]

Comment: Please post the launch agent log and your slave node config screenshot. On my end I only see the blue button you see and works for me.

Comment: Hi, Ben. I just uploaded the config screenshot to the OP. The log simply says:

[2018-10-17 08:05:20] [windows-slaves] Connecting to http://10.80.1.17
ERROR: [2018-10-17 08:05:20] The host name http://10.80.1.17 cannot be resolved. Please check that the host name is correct.

The problem is that the agent most definitely exists. I can ping everything. It all works. But I never received any setup details for the agent, so I felt like that might be the cause. Should it connect to the agent, and then, and only then, offer a slave.jar for the agent to download and configure?

Comment: Note, I removed the http:// and got farther, but I still get this error:
"org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Message not found for errorCode: 0xC0000001"

I made sure ports 139, 445 are allowed inbound and outbound in my firewall, but this error occurs anyway.

I am not getting the Orange "Launch" button as seen in this setup guide:
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217423827-How-to-Install-Several-Windows-Slaves-as-a-Service

Comment: OK now I understand what you are trying to do. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security -> To enable `TCP port for JNLP agents` set it to `Random`

In node configuration, change the Launch method to `Launch agent via Java Web Start`

Make sure Java is installed on your slave node

Now login to slave node, open browser and browse jenkins UI

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> Select the slave node

You should now see the Orange launch button. Click on the launch button to download the file

Now run the command shown on the screen in command prompt window

Slave should now be connected

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. Everything is set up and working now.